# Uploading an HTML file via HTML5

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest, html5-filesystem

I have this weird issue that Im not sure if its normal or not.. Im sure its not

I have a drag and drop area that I can upload any file and it works like a charm.

EXCEPT...

I cant upload any .html or .htm files with it. I can take an html file and rename it to .jpg and it works.

This is my piece of code:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open 'PUT', "#{tvr.api.url}/transfer/#{userprofile.UserLink.LinkID}/#{userprofile.UserLink.UserName}/#{channelid}/#{filename}"
xhr.upload.addEventListener "progress", (event, filename) =>
    window.Appbusy = true
    $($(".file-status-#{uid}").find("span")).text("(#{((event.loaded/event.totalSize)*100).toFixed(2)}%)")
,false
xhr.onreadystatechange = (aEvt) ->
  if xhr.readyState is 4
    if xhr.status is not 200
      $(".notification").remove()
      notification("The server returned an error uploading the file. Please try again.", 'error')
```

It even shows that upload progress then at 100% when it needs to push it the server it just fails with Bad Request. (the server never gets any request)

It works if the HTML file has 0 content! Why I do not know

**UPDATE:**

After some playing around I see that the request works when setting the Content-Type to text/plain:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

As soon as I change to text/html it does not work if the file has any content:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

***Could this be a bug?***

*I sent this as a possible XML bug*

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already (`$(".notification").remove()`, etc.), why not use jQuery to handle the put request?

Comment: I will try it and see if it makes any difference. I still think its an interesting issue

Comment: That does work... BUT WHY?

Comment: I can't say I know for sure. Were you receiving errors in the console before? I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead. Specify `type:'PUT'` for an upload. For example, using your URL:

```
$.ajax({
   type:"PUT"
   url:"#{tvr.api.url}/transfer/#{userprofile.UserLink.LinkID}/#{userprofile.UserLink.UserName}/#{channelid}/#{filename}"       
   success: function(){
      alert('success');
   }
});
```

Comment: IF you say instead, why? I dont think its a solution, although it works.

Comment: How would you get the progress of the upload?